# After upgrade CakePHP 3.2 to 3.3 - Display Errors: Controllers not found

Tags: cakephp, upgrade, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.3

I just upgraded my cakephp 3.2 to cakephp 3.3 using

```
composer upgrade
```

Just after the upgrade when I F5 the page, I started getting the following error:

```
Error: Create the class PagesController below in file: src\Controller\PagesController.php
```

But the controller exists and all was working before the upgrade. I checked the routes and app files and everything seens nice.

All controllers have the same error.

Have anyone a clue of what is going on?

thx

EDIT - I FOUND THE SOLUTION - But dunno what happened. If someone explain me I will be grateful

The problem is at the file

```
vendor/composer/autoload_static.php
```

In my old file I had the following configuration.

Inside:

```
public static $prefixLengthsPsr4 = array
```

I had

```
'A' => 
        array (
            'Aura\\Intl\\_Config\\' => 18,
            'App\\' => 4,
        ),
```

And add the array

```
'App\\' => 
        array (
            0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src',
        ),
```

To

```
public static $prefixDirsPsr4 = array (
```

But in the new file updated by composer the APP configuration was gone. I manually added it and it worked!

Does someone  knows why?

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: Hi systematical, i edited the post and added my routes on it

Comment: There is some problem at vendor/composer coz i have a bkp of my files and tried to manually update it. I broked exactly when I copied the composer folder